# How to call c# functions using ajax in razor web pages

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, razor

I am trying to add an upload form for my ecommerce site, and I need to have select boxes for category and subcategory. When I choose a category, I want an ajax function to autopopulate the other select box options with a list of subcategories from my sql server table of subcategories. I haven't been able to get the url part of the ajax function working, nor have I been able to find the right url to use with my c# class and cshtml page. Thank you. [this is the picture of the test ajax function that wanted to use for testing in my test cshtml page called list]
 (https://i.stack.imgur.com/988Rg.png)

```
@{ 
    Layout = "~/_SiteLayout3.cshtml";
}
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/Shared/MySite1.cs/GetData2") %>',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                $("#Content").text(response.d);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<form id="frm" method="post">
    <div id="Content">

    </div>

</form>

My C# Code

using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Services;


public static class MySite1
{
    [WebMethod]
    public static string GetData2()
    {
        return "This string is from Code behind";
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Ahmed, please try to put your code into the body of the question.

Comment: Okay, but it is just a test

Comment: Consider this link : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/get-the-data-from-asp-net-mvc-controller-using-jquery-ajax-and-bind-it-to-the-textbox

Comment: @Frankenstine Joe, i am not using mvc, i am using web pages, and I don't think I can add controllers and views to web pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Been a while for me, so if memory serves, in [ASP.Net Web Pages](https://www.asp.net/web-pages), it's more "bare metal". You'll have to handle the HTTP Requests yourself.

This **trivial** example uses `.cshtml`, but since this is all still "ASP.Net", you can use generic handlers (`.ashx`) as well (since there is no "content" needed, just some result handled by your XHR request).

```
<p>Ajax result appears below:</p>
<p id="result"></p>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#ajaxTest").on("click", function () {

            var request = $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/ajaxhandler",
                data: { "foo": "1234bar" }
            });

            request.done(function (d) {
                console.log(d);
                $("#result").text(d);
            });

            request.fail(function (xhr, err) {
                console.log("It died...%o", err);
            });
        });
    })
</script>
```

In the above `/ajaxhandler` is a `.cshmtl` file (as above you can use `.ashx` instead):

`ajaxhandler.cshtml`:

```
@{

    if (IsPost)
    {
        var payload = "";
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream))
        {
            payload = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/text");
        Response.Write(payload);

    }

}
```

You can extend this essentially by inspecting the HTTP request (e.g. url, fragment, query string etc.) and handle accordingly.

Hth.